# How are z-scores calculated if the data points to be centered appear several times in the data set?

Tags: z-score

I've collected the perceptions of brands in a survey and transferred them to another data set containing these brands.

The variables to operationalize brand perception are masculine (6 items) and feminine (6 items) brand perception, which are quantitative variables and vary from 1 to 7. I investigate the interaction effect of masculine and feminine brand perception, and therefore, I want to calculate the z-scores for the masculine and feminine brand perception scores

In the data set, however, brand x occurs 15 times and brand y 5 times. Consequently, the perception value of brand x is contained in the data set 15 times and that of y 5 times. If I want to calculate the z-scores of the brand perception values, the number of times x and y appear in the data set influences the z-scores for the brand perception. How do I handle this?

Comment: Your variable here really is ‘perceptions brand’ which is qualitative thus standardization is not defined.

Comment: There seems to be a completely different statistical question lurking: *why* do you want to compute Z-scores?  What do you hope that will accomplish?  Perhaps, if we were to know that, we could suggest appropriate procedures.

Comment: To be more specific: The variables to operationalize brand perception are masculine (6 items) and feminine (6 items) brand perception, which are quantitative variables and vary from 1 to 7. I investigate the interaction effect of masculine and feminine brand perception, and therefore, I want to calculate the z-scores for the masculine and feminine brand perception scores.

Comment: I deleted my answer since isn't related anymore to your query. Please update the post with this additional info. I don't see any issue with computing the scores, thought I doubt it may be more useful than the values themselves given the limited variability of the perceptions.

Comment: I assumed there might be an issue since the z-values (e.g., from the masculine brand perception) are different when I calculate them with the survey values (I only got 1 masculine brand perception for brand x and one for brand y here) and when I calculate them with the transferred values in the new data set (in this data set I got the value for the masculine brand perception of brand x 15 times and of brand y 5 times since x appears 15 times and y appears 5 times).